# I'm having difficulties with finding angle between tangent drawn from origin to a circle

Tags: geometry

Here is the question, $(x-7)^2 +(y+1)^2 =25$
When I solve it by geometrically I got the angle $\frac{π}{4}$+$\frac{π}{4}$ = $\frac{π}{2}$
But I want to learn any other idea solution if someone suggest me please. I tried to solve it with $tan\theta$ =  $\frac{m_1-m_2}{1+m_1m_2}$

I'm sorry I'm still not good at math jax. [this is what I tried](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8EP7.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you wish to find the slopes of the tangents and then apply the tangent compound-angle identity? You can find the slopes by letting $y=mx$ to be the tangent line, and find $m$ where the line and the circle equations together only has a double root.

Comment: I trier this but m values are not solving in quadratic form. I thought if I get two values of m then I'll find angle from M

Comment: Is there any possibility of derivatives solving this problem

Answer (score 1):

Imagine that there is only one tangent line coming from O(0, 0). That line must have an equation of the form y = mx for some m.

By assuming that the two objects are intersecting, we combine the two equations into a quadratic equation in x.

[Added:- Put $y = mx$ in $(x - 7)^2 + (y + 1)^2 = 25$ to get a quadratic equation in x. Re-arrangement of terms and simplifications are necessary. That equation will have m as part of the coefficients ]

---

Since there is only one point of contact, the two roots of that equation must be equal and hence the discriminant of that equation must be zero.

---

***That is, we set $(2m - 14)^2 - 4(1 + m^2)25 = 0$***. From that we get another quadratic equation in m. [$24m^2 + 14m -24= 0$]

That equation has 2 roots, namely $m_1$  and $m_2$. They correspond to the slopes of the two tangents.

Since $m_1 \times m_2 = product$ $of$ $roots = -24/24 = -1$, that means .....

Comment: I didn't understand how did you get this quadratic equation. Yes. This question has two roots and m1×m2 =-1 means they are perpendicular. Can you please make it more clear

Comment: @nawalarjun See the newly added part.

Comment: When I put y=mx i got
$ (1+m^2)x^2 +(2m-14)x+25=0$ what should I do next how to get m value from one equation

Comment: I don't know how did you get this equation now? Can you please write all the equation step by step so that i can understand better. Please it's very confusing now

Comment: @nawalarjun See also the bolded part.

Comment: How did you get this equation?

Comment: @nawalarjun See the explanation between the two rulers.

Comment: I'm sorry sir, it's complicated for me to understand how you got directly these two equations. I'll understand if you explain it step by step simply. Thank you

Comment: @nawalarjun I have tried by adding several detail steps already. Maybe you should let  somebody else (like your teacher) to explain to you about the logic of this article.

Comment: Thank you for helping, let me tell you about myself first. I'm preparing for a teaching exam.

Comment: I'm graduated by distance and I'm learning English too on my own. The equation you wrote I finally solved out. I read it again and again and found that $b^2= 4ac$ because it touches the circle. And you can already see my calculations which is pretty simple and very easy in starting of the this question. I have added that picture and second i want to learn this y=mx idea too. In the second day when I derivate it and put y=mx then it comes the quadratic equation you were saying. So must have mentioned these steps which is unclear or maybe my english reading skill is weak. Thank you

Comment: If you click over what I have tried in the question you will get my answer

Comment: @nawalarjun Glad to see that you can get through some of the hurdles. The method that I provide is not the simplest but is based on your request of looking for other ideas.

Comment: Yes mick, The confusing was I didn't know about D=0 which were easy. In the second way I had to derivated find value of X then out it back into general equation and got the quadratic equation in M... which is lengthy but intersting. I have got 2 more other ways to solve this question. We can find it through $tan= r/ roots$ where s is found when we put point into the equation. Second is $SS^1= T^2$ this pair of tangent formula

Answer (score 1):

This is going to be an unorthodox answer.

There is a formula i had derived to find the angle between tangents drawn from a point say P($x_1 , y_1$) to the circle,

S = $x^2+y^2+2gx+2fy+c$ = 0 (or) $(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=r^2$, where symbols have their usual meaning. (a , b being the centre of the circle, r being radius)

The formula is *tan $\frac{\theta}{2}$ = $\frac{r}{\sqrt {S_{11}}}$*
Here, $\theta$ is the angle between the tangents, r is the radius of the circle, $S_{11}$ is the value you get after putting in P($x_1 , y_1$) in S = 0 ,i .e, $S_{11}$ = $x_1^2+y_1^2+2gx_1+2fy_1+c$=0 (or) $(x_1-a)^2+(y_1-b)^2=r^2$

So your answer now is, tan $\frac{\theta}{2}$ = $\frac{5}{\sqrt {25}}$

Therefore, $\theta$ = $\frac{π}{2}$

here, P is (0,0), $S_{11}$ = $(0-7)^2+(0+1)^2-25=25$

Another way to solve this is by using the general equation of pair of tangents to a circle $(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=r^2$ with centre (a,b), i,e,
(y - b) = (mx-a) ± r $\sqrt {1+m^2}$, So in this case the pair tangents become y + 1 = mx - 7 ± 5 $\sqrt {1+m^2}$ and taking any one tangent and solve it with circle and since it only touches the circle at one point, using determinant of the quadratic as zero, we can obtain $12m^2+7m−12=0$ and on observation product of roots $m_1m_2=-1$, proving tangents are perpendicular.

Comment: $Y+1=mx-7+-5root1+m^2$   Ididn't understand how did you solve this and got directly $12 m^2+7m-12=0$